# Responsive html with absolute position text inside relative positon picture

Tags: html, css, css-position

What I'm trying to do, is an HTML page split in two colors and
position a resizable image in the middle and on top show some positioned text.

I've managed to do it, but the problem is that when I resize the window,
image resizes just fine, but the text div loses its position.

```css
.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f1b900 0%, #f1b900 50%, #000000 50%, #272660 50%, #272660 100%);
  /* W3C */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 300ms;
  height: 100%;
}
.folderimg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("folder.png") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.foldername {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-55eg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  font-size: 4vmin;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="folderimg">
    <div class="foldername">Test Username</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apsillas/w1om0h0o)

Some help would be really appreciable...

Comment: make a jsfiddle on jsfiddle.net.. but absolute positioning is a bit of a no-no in responsive design..

Comment: If you provide pictures with how you want it to look on desktop and mobile, i'm willing to answer with the necessary CSS, so you (and perhaps others) can have an example of how this is done by someone who's usually payed to get this type of jobs done. Right now your code is sub-par, and will most likely not behave the way you want it on some devices and screen widths. That's my best offer, as a "welcome to SO" gift.

Comment: Andrei indeed it is a sub-par, but I believe that if I manage to  make it work, then I'll be able to embedded on my main code. I just added jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use img tag instead of background-image, we can set size of container tag by size of img tag.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="folder">
    <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/qi3kmv39d/folder.png">
    <div class="foldername">Test Username</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
  /*...*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.folder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.folder img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 50vw;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
.foldername {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-55eg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  font-size: 3vmin;
}
```

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/w1om0h0o/2/

Hope it can help

Comment: Yes! Thank you Peter. I knew it that the solution had to do smth with vw and vh measurement. But I was totally lost. Thank you again